# I have a Mariner 5 HP outboard. I need info please?

Tags: troubleshooting, boat

My Mariner is a 5 HP model 5M,  Code 6E3  S, and Serial # 148968. I'd like to know who made it, what year model it is. Help Please !

Comment: Welcome to the site. We can probably get you the manufacturer and model, but asking for parts sources is off-topic for the site. I'll modify your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks,  I have determined that the engine is Japanese and manufactured in 1986. I need either a new carb or a carb rebuild kit. The engine is like new but the diaphragm no longer functions probably due to age.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.autorepairmanuals.biz/page/608055), it's a 1986 motor, and it's actually a 5C M.
According to [this other site](http://www.marineengine.com/boat-forum/showthread.php?381337-Mariner-5M-6e3), they were built by Yamaha for Mercury.

Comment: Thanks, Yamaha is good. I have ridden and raced Yamaha Cycles for years.